# Complete documentation on Discord embeds

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have now been searching for a good and reliable source of documentation about the Discord embed-system, but couldnt find any. I am of course aware about the offical documentation on discord.js.org and discordjs.guide, but they lack support and explanation of the embed-object that discord supports. To describe my problem precisely, I have been trying to add a button to a discord embed-object. What I have right now is this basic template for testing purposes:

````
const embed = {
            "title": "Hello ~~people~~ world :wave:",
            "description": "You can use [links](https://discord.com) or emojis :smile: \n```\nAnd also code blocks\n```",
            "color": 4321431,
            "timestamp": "2022-07-03T18:07:18.372Z",
            "url": "https://discord.com",
            "author": {
                "name": "Author name",
                "url": "https://discord.com",
                "icon_url": "https://unsplash.it/100"
            },
            "thumbnail": {
                "url": "https://unsplash.it/200"
            },
            "image": {
                "url": "https://unsplash.it/380/200"
            },
            "footer": {
                "text": "Footer text",
                "icon_url": "https://unsplash.it/100"
            },
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "Field 1, *lorem* **ipsum**, ~~dolor~~",
                    "value": "Field value"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Field 2",
                    "value": "You can use custom emojis <:Kekwlaugh:722088222766923847>. <:GangstaBlob:742256196295065661>",
                    "inline": false
                },
                {
                    "name": "Inline field",
                    "value": "Fields can be inline",
                    "inline": true
                },
                {
                    "name": "Inline field",
                    "value": "*Lorem ipsum*",
                    "inline": true
                },
                {
                    "name": "Inline field",
                    "value": "value",
                    "inline": true
                },
                {
                    "name": "Another field",
                    "value": "> Nope, didn't forget about this",
                    "inline": false
                }
            ]
    }
````

I have only been able to find documentation about the internal commands of dicord.js, that use the ".set("Value")" syntax to add buttons and dropdowns to the embed.

It would be really helpful, if someone could provide me a link to a nice and detailed documentation that would ideally include all available "subcommands" for an embed object.
Any other kind of help is also very much appreciated!
Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Buttons are not on embeds, buttons are on *messages*. Just like embeds which are also on messages. They are just 2 different parts of a message.

Answer (score 0):

There is an official documentation about messages in discord developer docs, here is the documentation that you need  https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/message-components